# Fatal Error: mpi.h No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, mpi

I'm a new linux user. I'm getting this error during compilation. When I use the 'make' command within a build directory.

```
Fatal Error: mpi.h No such file or directory
```

I've installed OpenMpi using this:

```
sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev
```

I found the folder where mpi.h is located: and I attempted to add it to path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include
```

I still get the same error when I try 'make'. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Edit: I think I'm using the G++ compiler, here's the full error message:

```
 Making all in Ipopt
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt'
Making all in src/Common
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/Common'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/Common'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/Common'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/Common'
Making all in src/LinAlg
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/LinAlg'
Making all in TMatrices
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/LinAlg/TMatrices'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/LinAlg/TMatrices'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/LinAlg'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/LinAlg'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/LinAlg'
Making all in src/Algorithm
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/Algorithm'
Making all in LinearSolvers
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers'
if /bin/bash ../../../../libtool --tag=CXX --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I`echo ../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers` -I../../../src/Common  -I`echo ../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../Common` -I`echo ../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../LinAlg` -I`echo ../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../LinAlg/TMatrices` -I`echo ../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/..` -I`echo ../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../Interfaces` -I`echo ../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../contrib/CGPenalty` -I/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/include/coin-or/mumps    -O3 -pipe -DNDEBUG -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-long-long   -DIPOPT_BUILD -MT IpMumpsSolverInterface.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/IpMumpsSolverInterface.Tpo" -c -o IpMumpsSolverInterface.lo ../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/IpMumpsSolverInterface.cpp; \
then mv -f ".deps/IpMumpsSolverInterface.Tpo" ".deps/IpMumpsSolverInterface.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/IpMumpsSolverInterface.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
 g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers -I../../../src/Common -I../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../Common -I../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../LinAlg -I../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../LinAlg/TMatrices -I../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/.. -I../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../Interfaces -I../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/../../contrib/CGPenalty -I/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/include/coin-or/mumps -O3 -pipe -DNDEBUG -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-long-long -DIPOPT_BUILD -MT IpMumpsSolverInterface.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/IpMumpsSolverInterface.Tpo -c ../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/IpMumpsSolverInterface.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/IpMumpsSolverInterface.o
../../../../../Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers/IpMumpsSolverInterface.cpp:22:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
 #include "mpi.h"
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:569: recipe for target 'IpMumpsSolverInterface.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [IpMumpsSolverInterface.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/Algorithm/LinearSolvers'
Makefile:688: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt/src/Algorithm'
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rory/Packages/Ipopt/build/Ipopt'
Makefile:323: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
```

Comment: You need to set the C++ compiler to `mpic++`. It is a wrapper around the system C++ compiler that passes it all the necessary arguments needed to find the MPI header file and link the necessary MPI libraries. That's usually achieved by setting the `CXX` variable in the environment.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind telling me the command line to do this I'm very new? I've only set environments variables before with expor X='Y' Also I don't appear to have a CXX environment variable at the moment, is this abnormal?

Comment: `export CXX=mpic++ && make` or simply `CXX=mpic++ make`. `CXX` is not normally set in the environment, in which case `make` uses the default value.

Comment: @HristoIliev Hmm it seems to not have worked.

Comment: @HristoIliev Nevermind, you solved it. But I had to go back a ./configure again before I could make.

Comment: Well, if your `Makefile` is generated by GNU Autotools, you have to set `CXX` when running the `configure` script.